# accessing json file in a correct manner

Tags: json, swift

I am accessing an API to retrieve data of a player.

When I send a GET request using AlamoFire,  I get below result for `JSON[summonerName.lowercaseString]!`:

```
{
    id = 11111111;
    name = example;
    profileIconId = 1;
    revisionDate = 1111971248000;
    summonerLevel = 30;
}
```

I just want to retrieve `id` value.

I thought this was a dictionary so I did `JSON[summonerName.lowercaseString]!["id"]` but it is complaining that I cannot subscript AnyObject. How can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler does not know the type of `JSON[summonerName.lowercaseString]`, it can not use it as a dictionary. You know it's a dictionary, but the compiler doesn't.

Help by specifying the type:

```
if let object = JSON[summonerName.lowercaseString] as? [String:AnyObject] {
   if let id = object["id"] as? Int {
        // use id
   }
   if let name = object["name"] as? String {
        // use name
   }
}
```

etc.